# how to combine or merge two strings in java?

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

Below is my code I'm expecting the output as **"afbgchde"** and **not** **"abcdefgh"** but ending up with out of index error, Hope there is a better way to get this..Please help..!!

```
String str1 = "abcde";
//char[] a = str1.toCharArray();
//System.out.println(a);
String str2 = "fgh";
char[] b = str2.toCharArray();
//System.out.println(b);
int i,j=0;
try
    {
        for(i=0;i<str1.length();i++)
        {
          char c = str1.charAt(i);
          System.out.print(c);
          if(j==i)
          { 
            char d = str2.charAt(j);
            System.out.print(d);
            j++;
          }
        }
    }
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Where is the error, and what have you done to think about why you're getting it?

Comment: @JonSkeet I understood that the error is due to index value of str2 is causing the error but not getting how to handle it..

Comment: Well think about *why* you're asking for a value that's out of range, and what you want to do instead. Hint: if you were asked to merge "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" and "12" would you keep going after you'd got to "c"?

Answer (score 4):

Simple:

```
 char d = str2.charAt(j);
 System.out.print(d);
 j++;
```

You are accessing chars in your second string; but you never bother to check if `j` is still `< str2.length()`.

Meaning: your for-loop for `i` contains that check; and prevents going beyond the length of `str` ... but then you forget to do that on your other string! So your merge only works when str and str2 happen to have the same size.

So a solution would more look like:

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 int j = 0;
 for (int i=0; i < str.length(); i++) {
   builder.append(str.charAt(i));
   if (j < str2.length()) {
     builder.append(str2.charAt(j));  
     j++;
   }
 }
 // if str2 has more chars than str
 if (j < str2.length()) {
   // append ALL chars starting from index j
   builder.append(str2.substring(j));
 }
 String merged = builder.toString();
```

Comment: Your btw is wrong, if you look at what he wants to do: he doesn't want to get `abcdefgh`, but `afbgchde`. So he doesn't want to simply concat them, but to do another operation (shown by his example)

Comment: Thanks, overlooked that part.

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you, When length is equal code works perfect else getting error...It will be heplful if you could give some more details as I'm just started learning java

Comment: I updated my example (didnt compile/run it; so be aware of subtle typos or so). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Complete Code for your combiner.

```
public class StringCombiner {
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(combine("Hello", "World"));
    System.out.println(combine("He", "World"));
    System.out.println(combine("Hello", "Wo"));
}

    public static String combine(String str1, String str2){
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        int i =0;
        for(; i< str1.length(); ++i){
            output.append(str1.charAt(i));
            if(i < str2.length()){
                output.append(str2.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        if(i < str2.length()){
            for(; i<str2.length(); ++i){
                output.append(str2.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
    }
```

Output:

```
HWeolrllod
HWeorld
HWeollo
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm trying to get afbgchde

Comment: Hey @RamrajSekar misunderstood the question first. Added the complete code now. Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Lets try this

```
String str1 = "abcde";
String str2 = "fgh";
int bigLength = str1.length()>str2.length()?str1.length():str2.length();

for(int i = 0; i<bigLength; i++){
if(i<str1.length())
   System.out.print(str1.charAt(i))
if(i<str2.length())
   System.out.print(str2.charAt(i))
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I'm trying to get afbgchde not abcdefgh

Comment: modified. Have a look.

Comment: This one worked,Thank you..!!

Comment: If it is effective then could you mark it is a right answer? I hope you could.

Answer (score 0):

just use StringBuilder class man

> if  you want to change a value of a String object

String class is an object that is unchangeable or can't be change when it is initialized

StringBuilder class is the best solution for any String that you want to have a change while the application is running

> e.g. add a String or change value of a String or even shorten a String

that is the power of StringBuilder class

`